# New mobile web theme, or bug?

Tags: support, mobile-web

I just noticed the main mobile web site theme changed, it's now a SE's look (light blue theme), someone know if it is normal ? (SF's meta is still ok on the other hand)

Thanks !

[image]

For reference, how it looked like, and how SF's meta still look;
[image]

Comment: A new mobile-web theme was rolled out a couple of days ago, it seems.

Comment: @Oded If not a bug, you answer me, as I though the mobile web theme was supposed to follow the normal theme of the main site. (like it was before, but it was maybe a cooincidance that the old theme was the same as SF's theme too)

Comment: The old theme was the same theme for all sites - there was no specific "SF" mobile theme.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for the clarification! If you write that as a answer, I will accept then and close this discusion

Comment: [There isn't always a difference.](http://globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/not_a_bug_but_a_feature.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We only had a single mobile theme to *all* sites in the past.

The new theme is in place to allow us to do some per-site customization, but the current one for SF is the one shared by most sites.